# use git bash to access team foundation server

Tags: git, bash, authentication, tfs, command

when I try to clone project from team foundation server, below info always show up:

```
$ git clone http://ns158z:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_git/ezrama
Cloning into 'ezrama'...
```

> fatal: unable to access
>   'http://ns158z:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_git/ezrama/':  The
>   requested URL returned error: 502

and it seems to be a error of Authentication~

Ps.I use git-bash in windows, should I install some other software??

Comment: Is that the correct URL that TFS gives you for that repository?

Comment: the server is set in company private domain and it's the reason that the address seems strange. however, it's correct and workable when I use tfs in visual studio 2013. But, I prefer to use git bash and it just can't work fine in git command line interface.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably running into the issue that has actually 
[been documented by Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2867441).

> - You create a team project that uses Git as the source control engine in TFS 2013.
> - You connect to this Git remote repository on the TFS server by using a third-party Git client.
> - You try to execute a large request by using Git. For example, you clone many files.

#### As per their site:

**Cause**:

This issue occurs because of an issue in the ARR 2.5 feature.

**Resolution**:

To resolve this issue, [install the ARR 2.5 update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2589179).

Good luck.